# access values of controls dynamically created on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

My problem is:
I've got a table, dynamically created, fill with a lot of dropdownlists witches IDs are dynamically created.

When a button is pressed, I need to scan all controls in the table and save their value.

But after the postback I can't no longer access to the table, and I've no idea how can I get those values...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controls created dynamically must be created again on every postback on the event Init or PreInit (before ViewState is loaded) otherwise you won't be able to retrieve their values.

Some reference links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic4

https://web.archive.org/web/20210707024005/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081402-1.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20210707024009/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/082102-1.aspx

Comment: +1 You can do it in the Page_Load() event, too, as long as you don't reset the values.

Comment: Actually I want to query whether you can do it in the Page_Load or not. I tried in the Page_Load() event (nothing else happening but creating the controls again) and it didn't bind the values back to the controls. Also looking at the MSDN article above on ViewState, it seems that the ViewState load happens well before the Page_Load event.

Answer (score 2):

If the form was posted, shouldn't they be in the Request.Forms collection.

Let's say you named them all starting with dct.

Then you could loop through the collection and taking what values you need.

You could access the values with Request.Form("dct_001") etc...

Since the lookup is string based you could put it in a loop to catch the value.

BTW this classic ASP approach still works in 4.0

Comment: I am struggling with similar problem. Can you pleas look at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43949678/aspx-get-value-of-dynamically-added-text-box