# How to Retrieve Values of A Dynamically Created Control's Child Controls on PostBack?

Tags: asp.net, postback, dynamic-controls

Given: I have a custom server control in the markup of an aspx page. This control creates child controls in its `CreateChildControls()` method (e.g. it retrieves content from a database and based on that content dynamically creates either a `CheckBoxList` or a `RadioButtonList`)

Now I understand that I cannot access the dynamically created controls on postback unless I add them again on Page_Init or Page_PreInit (as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019760/access-values-of-controls-dynamically-created-on-postback)).

My question is, **how do I add them again explicitly in Page_Init or Page_PreInit if they are just going to be added yet again when we get around to calling `Render()` on each of the custom server controls?**

I'm very certain this is not a unique problem, so there must be a best practice way of doing it...I just don't know what it is :/

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is create you Custom server control in the Pre_Init.  Everything else is handled for you.  I think you're thinking too hard about what is going on and it's confusing :)

The custom control will render the child controls while in the Pre_Init event.  They won't get rendered twice.

Comment: Unfortunately I need custom server controls to be in the markup in this case :( - would that be solved by a level of indirection, e.g. I have a FigureHeadCustomControl with DBID="123" in the markup, then in Pre_Init I dynamically create an instance of TheRealCustomControl (passing the DBID through), with TheRealCustomControl rendering the child controls?