# Aspx get value of dynamically added text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've added two text boxes dynamically on the aspx page.

I would like to get values from those two text boxes on the server side after postback (after Btn1 is clicked).

And here is my first problem - controls are not found. 
I've tried to find controls with:

```
Page.FindControl("txt4");
```

What is wrong with this? Isn't the whole page posted back with all the controls in it?

My other question is - where in the code to get those values? In the Page_load event, before they are re-added? I guess when Btn1_Click event is triggered, those two controls are already re-added, so values from original postback are lost? (Page_load event is triggered before Btn1_Click).

I am really struggling with this.

It is much easier if controls are added through markup - they are directly accesible in code behind by theirs ID. But on the project that I work currently controls are mostly added dynamically, and a lot of them.

Code behind:

```
  public partial class About : Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      btn1.Click += Btn1_Click;

      if(IsPostBack)
     {
        System.Web.UI.Control txt4_dynamic = Page.FindControl("txt4");
        System.Web.UI.Control txt5_dynamic = Page.FindControl("txt5");

        if(txt4_dynamic != null)
        {
            string str1 = ((TextBox)txt4_dynamic).Text;          
        }

        if (txt5_dynamic != null)
        {
            string str1 = ((TextBox)txt5_dynamic).Text;
        }
     }

      TextBox txt4 = new TextBox();
      txt4.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
      txt4.ID = "txt4";     

      TextBox txt5 = new TextBox();
      txt5.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
      txt5.ID = "txt5";

      panel1.Controls.Add(txt4);
      panel1.Controls.Add(txt5);


    }

    private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
      System.Web.UI.Control txt4_dynamic = Page.FindControl("txt4");
      System.Web.UI.Control txt5_dynamic = Page.FindControl("txt5");

      if (txt4_dynamic != null)
      {
          string str1 = ((TextBox)txt4_dynamic).Text;
      }

      if (txt5_dynamic != null)
      {
          string str1 = ((TextBox)txt5_dynamic).Text;
      }
    }
  }
```

Markup:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

  <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

  <asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">    
  </asp:Panel>

</asp:Content>
```

**UPDATE:**

I've updated my code with:

```
   protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(IsPostBack)
  {
    TextBox txt4 = new TextBox();
    txt4.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
    txt4.ID = "txt4";

    TextBox txt5 = new TextBox();
    txt5.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
    txt5.ID = "txt5";

    panel1.Controls.Add(txt4);
    panel1.Controls.Add(txt5);

    string st1 = txt4.Text;
    string st2 = txt5.Text;


    System.Web.UI.Control txt4_dynamic = Page.FindControl("txt4");
    System.Web.UI.Control txt5_dynamic = Page.FindControl("txt5");

    if (txt4_dynamic != null)
    {
      string str1 = ((TextBox)txt4_dynamic).Text;
    }

    if (txt5_dynamic != null)
    {
      string str1 = ((TextBox)txt5_dynamic).Text;
    }
  }
}
```

I've checked the code in debugger - controls are added on postback, but values for st1, st2, txt4_dynamic and txt5_dynamic are still empty / null.

**UPDATE 2:**

There were two problems:

1. Finding control should be done with:

> ```
> Page.Controls[0].FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("txt4");
> ```

2. Code above finds controls text only in controls events (and they are triggered after `Page_Load`).

So: Everything can stay as I originally posted - the only change needed is code for finding control, which must be in `click` event. If this same code is in `Page_Load` event, it will not work.

Comment: please accept the answer if it worked for you so that it is clear for others.

Comment: @Boney - I've updated question.

Comment: I meant to move that piece of code alone to Page_Init. Not the full code. Anyways I have updated the answer now with full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the code to as below (basically move the dynamic control creation/addition to `Page_Init`):

```
public partial class About : Page
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt4 = new TextBox();
        txt4.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
        txt4.ID = "txt4";

        TextBox txt5 = new TextBox();
        txt5.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
        txt5.ID = "txt5";

        panel1.Controls.Add(txt4);
        panel1.Controls.Add(txt5);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn1.Click += Btn1_Click;

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            System.Web.UI.Control txt4_dynamic = Page.Controls[0].FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("txt4");
            System.Web.UI.Control txt5_dynamic = Page.Controls[0].FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("txt5");

            if (txt4_dynamic != null)
            {
                string str1 = ((TextBox)txt4_dynamic).Text;
            }

            if (txt5_dynamic != null)
            {
                string str1 = ((TextBox)txt5_dynamic).Text;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.UI.Control txt4_dynamic = Page.Controls[0].FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("txt4");
        System.Web.UI.Control txt5_dynamic = Page.Controls[0].FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("txt5");

        if (txt4_dynamic != null)
        {
            string str1 = ((TextBox)txt4_dynamic).Text;
        }

        if (txt5_dynamic != null)
        {
            string str1 = ((TextBox)txt5_dynamic).Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Control tree is created at server side on each postback. Since controls are added dynamically they need to be added on each postback, which you are already doing.

Reason for moving that code to `Page_Init` event is that, values posted from clientside are set in `LoadPostData` event which happens after `Page_Init` and before `Page_Load`.
When you have the code in `Page_Init`, by the time `LoadPostData` event happens control tree is already created and posted value is correctly set.
When you had the code in `Page_Load`, `LoadPostData` event happened even before the control was created and posted value was not set.

Comment: Does this example works for you? If you insert some text on both textboxes - do you see that text on the server side after button click? I don't see that text, and both text boxes are not found in the page_load / btn1_click event.

Comment: Yes the code i have posted above works fine. Are you using the exact same code or you have some modifications ?

Comment: No, I don't have any modifications. I am using default project, created from VS2015 - Projects - Web application - ASP.NET web forms. Inside 'about' is my code.

Comment: Ok i got it why it is not working for you. I'm not using Master Page and hence `Page.FindControl("txt4");' works for me and not you. Let me see how to change that line for it to work for you.

Comment: Ok. I have updated the code now. It should work for you now. You can probably add some null check/index check and/or find a better way of finding the control from the Page object. `FindControl` method is not recursive. So you have to find control by control.

Comment: Boney thanks a lot for your effort, you were really helpful.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!